# Prevent text from overriding in Sketch

Tags: sketch-app, interface-design, symbols

I have a vacancy card with fixed and negotiable salary. They can be switched using overrides. But when I change salary to negotiable I don't want text in that symbol to change. I want it to be locked from changes and display "negotiable salary". However, when I type custom text in fixed salary symbol and then switch it to negotiable - negotiable salary's symbol text changes to one of values of the previous symbol.

[image: my symbols]

You can see that "Negotiable salary" text field is locked but when I switch override I get "2389" which is not something I have in the original symbol.

[image: symbol page screen]

By the way, sometimes negotiable salary text field displays text written in currency field, so I suppose it's a bug. I hope explanation was clear, please give some advice as it drives me crazy.

**How can I lock the text from being changed when switching overrides?**

Answer (score 2):

I was able to handle this case by having the same structure in both symbols:

- Salary
- Currency
- Negotiable salary

Then I hid the irrelevant layers and locked them, so ppl couldn't change them.

This way, Sketch has the same override properties it's looking for and doesn't make a mess when you go back and forth. You can also check out the file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/w3n2bflyjduykv1/card-override-issue.sketch?dl=0 
(I went into less detail while building the design than you)

[image]

[image: File Structure]